# How to pass dependencies to a custom .NET Core ILoggerProvider

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I am creating a custom .NET Core `ILoggerProvider` that requires some dependencies to be passed into its constructor.

I believe I am using a fairly common pattern to initialize my logging implementation; it looks something like this:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

// Register some services here

services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddProvider(new DebugLoggerProvider());
});

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

I want to add my new provider within the `AddLogging` block, in the same way that the `DebugLoggerProvider` is currently added.

My custom provider requires some other services to be passed into its constructor and since these are already registered with the `ServiceCollection`, I assume that I should be able to reference them. However, unlike methods such as `AddSingleton`, which have an overload that exposes the `IServiceProvider`, `AddLogging` doesn't seem to offer an equivalent.

Is there a simple way to achieve this, or am I attempting to do something that contradicts the way .NET Core logging was designed to be deployed?

UPDATE:

After experimenting with the suggestions proposed by @Nkosi, I can confirm that it is possible to get this to work by bypassing `AddLogging` and directly implementing what it does internally, as follows:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

// Register some services
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();

// Initialize logging
services.AddOptions();
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(p => new DebugLoggerProvider());
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(p => new MyLoggerProvider("Constant value", p.GetService<IMyService>()));

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Now I am not sure if an extension already exists to do this but I see potential here.

First this is how [`AddProvider`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingBuilderExtensions.cs,35) is defined in the source code repo.

```
public static ILoggingBuilder AddProvider(this ILoggingBuilder builder, ILoggerProvider provider) {
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(provider);
    return builder;
}
```

You could build up on that by making your own generic version

```
public static class MyLoggingBuilderExtensions {
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddProvider<T>(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
        where T: class, ILoggerProvider{
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, T>();
        return builder;
    }
}
```

which should allow the DI container to build up the object graph when resolved

```
services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddProvider<CustomLoggerProvider>();
});
```

And there is room to extend this functionality, like adding your own overload that exposes the `IServiceProvider` and passing that on to the `AddSingleton` within the extension.

```
public static ILoggingBuilder AddProvider<T>(this ILoggingBuilder builder, Func<IServiceProvider, T> factory)
    where T: class, ILoggerProvider {
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, T>(factory);
    return builder;
}
```

And used

```
services.AddLogging(builder => {
    builder.AddProvider<CustomLoggerProvider>(p => new CustomLoggerProvider("Constant value", p.GetService<IMyService>()));
});
```

Comment: That's a genius solution - thank you :) As you say, it seems like the kind of thing that should exist already but, assuming it doesn't I am happy to adopt your extension into my codebase.

Comment: After testing this, I have discovered that it doesn't work exactly as I expected. If my custom provider has a parameterless constructor, it works. But as soon as I introduce dependencies that need to be injected, it fails when attempting to resolve them. Could this be because the IServiceCollection used by ILoggingBuilder is separate to the main DI ServiceCollection?

Comment: It is a possibility. Try registering the other dependencies and see if it works. That would prove it.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that only way that this will work is when the entire dependency chain is resolved (i.e. create instances of all dependencies) before adding the provider to the logging builder. I tried replicating the DI definitions of all dependencies (and their dependencies) inside AddLogging (which is also ugly) but it still failed. It seems as if this logging implementation has a large hole in it.

Comment: @TimCoulter that is odd as from investigating further in the repo I can see it is using the same service collection https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L32

Comment: You're right, and I have finally got this to work by unwrapping what AddLogging does internally and implementing it inline, as shown in the update to my post. I am still not clear why this doesn't work using the extension method, but I think this is a reasonable outcome. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Great solution. Minor issue with the 2nd code block definition provided: "where T: ILoggerProvider, class" should be "where T: class, ILoggerProvider" (at least VS complained...)

Comment: Base on their GitHub AddProvider on ILoggerFactory has been obsoleted https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/238

Comment: You can go even further and use `var loggerProvider = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<LoggerFileProvider>(provider);` which allows dependencies in the logger constructor too

Answer (score 1):

I got a simple solution to work which is kinda lighter.

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging(logBuilder =>
{
    logBuilder.AddConfiguration(theConfigRoot.GetSection("Logging"));
});
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLogProvider>();
```

However.... Instanciating the Provider keeps you from running in circular dependency problems--> The service you may want to inject soon want´s a logger himself^^

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for being a bit late to the party on this one, but I ran into exactly the same problem after having searched high and low. Inspired by the excellent entries in this page, I ended up with the solution below.

```
services.AddTransient<IMyLogRepository, LogRepository>();
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole()
                   .AddDbLoggerProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IMyLogRepository>());
        });
        services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory.CreateLogger("MyLogging"));
```

The key to this being:

```
services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IMyLogRepository>())
```

Which allowed me to link my database repository to the dbLogger object I created in a single extra line. In essence, it gives me the ability to pluck my DI database object an send it to the Logging service via standard `ILoggerProvider` and `ILogger` interfaces