# Calling BuildServiceProvider inside of HostBuilder to get access to a service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, service-provider

I am using .Net Core v2.2.  I need to pass IHttpClientFactory into my custom LoggerProvider.  In order to access this service from within ConfigureLogging, I can do this:

```
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logBuilder) =>
{
    var factory = logBuilder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService(typeof(IHttpClientFactory)) as IHttpClientFactory;
    logBuilder.AddProvider(new SlackLoggerProvider(factory));
})
```

I think `BuildServiceProvider()` ends up creating a duplicate set of services.  Is this OK?  It is working but I am wondering if this is going to affect the lifecycle or performance of IHttpClientFactory.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption based on provided code is

```
public class SlackLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider {
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory clientFactory;

    public SlackLoggerProvider(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory) {
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    //...
}
```

Add the necessary types to the service collection so that they can be resolved by the framework at run-time

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, SlackLoggerProvider>();
        });
```

The added types will be available to the log builder when starting up.

All `AddProvider` extension does in the shown example is add the `ILoggerProvider` derived instance as a singleton to the service collection.

```
public static ILoggingBuilder AddProvider(this ILoggingBuilder builder, ILoggerProvider provider)
{
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(provider);
    return builder;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging/src/LoggingBuilderExtensions.cs#L34)

You can take it a step further and add an extension

```
public static class SlackLoggerBuilderExtension {
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddSlack(this ILoggingBuilder builder) {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, SlackLoggerProvider>();
        //or
        //builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(sp => 
        //    new SlackLoggerProvider(sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>())
        //);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

ensuring that required dependencies are added.

and used

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logBuilder) => {
            logBuilder.AddSlack();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
.ConfigureLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, SlackLoggerProvider>();
})
```

Then you can use dependency injection as usual:

```cs
public class SlackLoggerProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public SlackLoggerProvider(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
}
```

You just need to add the `IHttpClientFactory` to your service collection:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ⋮
    services.AddHttpClient();
    ⋮
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The answer I provided above does cause a `StackOverflowException`. I believe this is due to this line:

https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/7c4f9479b4753a37c8b0669a883002e5e448cc94/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L29

The code that is building the HttpClient is calling the code that is adding logging, which in this case is again calling the code that is building the HttpClient... until the stack overflows.

So it appears the approach you use in the question is probably the best way to do what you're trying to do, as it resolves everything before sending it to your logger.

Comment: That throws a StackOverFlowException.  If I remove the IHttpClientFactory as a dependency to SlackLoggerProvider it does not throw an exception.

Comment: I tried this and it still gives a StackOverflowException: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991469/how-to-pass-dependencies-to-a-custom-net-core-iloggerprovider