# Unit Testing with ILoggerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the code like this in my unit test setup:

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<IDependency, Dependency>();
services.AddLogging();
services.RemoveAll<ILoggerProvider>();
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyCustomProvider>(provider =>
{
    var myDependency = provider.GetService<IDependency>();
    return new MyCustomProvider(myDependency );
});
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger>();
```

When I run this `logger` is null.

The lambda for the DI factory to create `MyCustomProvider` is never called.  Nor is the constructor to `MyCustomProvider` nor the constructor of the class I made that implements `ILogger`.

I am guessing that I am missing a step to wire this up.  But there is a lot of conflicting documentation out there between .Net Core 1, 2 and 3.

**What do I need to do to wire up my provider the .Net Core 3 way?**  (Such that I can get an `ILogger` that uses it.)

NOTES:

- I don't call `LoggingBuilder.AddProvider`.  But if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/2d2f31968229eddb57b6ba3d34696ef366a6c71b/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingBuilderExtensions.cs#L22) for that extension, it just calls `AddSingleton`, which is what I do, but with a factory.  (Got the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50991749/16241).)
- Similarly `services.RemoveAll<ILoggerProvider>()` is the same as calling `ClearProviders`.
- My goal is to simulate an injection of an ILogger into a class constructor.

For Example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     public SomeClass(ILogger<SomeClass> logger)
     {
          // Do Stuff
     }
}
```

Somehow this is done without indicating any provider.  I would like to make it be the same in my unit test.  (Just use my custom provider.)

Comment: hi have you tried something like     services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, NullLoggerFactory>();

Answer (score 3):

The reason your `logger` variable is `null` in the *example* is because `ILogger` isn't actually registered as a service. If you look at the source of `AddLogging` you can see it only registers `ILogger<>` and `ILoggerFactory`. If you've ever tried to accept an `ILogger` instead of an `ILogger<MyClass>` via the .NET Core DI you will have run into the following exception*:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate
>   'Your.Service'

Based on this, your *testing* code is flawed as you'd never have received an `ILogger` in the first place. To see that you're code is in fact *working*, modify your testing code so that it retrieves an `ILogger<SomeClass>` instead. The result of your variable will be non-null and a break point set in your provider's constructor will be hit:

```
// Get*Required*Service won't throw
var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
```

If you *want* to be able to inject `ILogger`, you will need to register it separately with a default category name**:

```
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyCustomProvider>(); // no need for lambda
services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(sp => 
  sp.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger("Default")
);
```

The following will both now work *and* use your custom provider:

```
var loggerA = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
var loggerB = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
```

I have my own custom provider/factory/logger that I use to inject xUnit's `ITestOutputHelper` into a custom logger following the same registration pattern as you, so I know from personal experience that this works. But I've also tested that your specific code is functional (mocking out my own `IDependency`)--the above code is executed and breakpoints set in the constructor of `MyCustomProvider` and the service registration are hit. Additionally, if I inject the logger into a class it's hit as well (as expected).

Your comment "Somehow this is done without indicating any provider" is misinformed, because you do in fact have a provider registered! But even in a scenario where all providers were cleared and no new ones were added, you'd still get a non-null logger. This is because `LoggerFactory` just loops through each provider to build up a new logger *wrapper* around them. If there's no providers then you essentially get a no-op logger.

* This is unfortunate as some tools (like R#) will suggest converting the parameter to the base type `ILogger` which then breaks DI!

** A default category name is required since there is no generic type argument to pass to `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger`. For the generic `ILogger<T>` the category name is always a variation of `T`'s name--but we obviously don't get that with the non-generic version. If I had to *guess*, this is probably why they don't register an implementation of `ILogger` by default.

Answer (score 0):

NET CORE Testing I'm doing like this:

in the constructor of the test class (or where you do your DI mapping)

```
public class UnitTest1
    {

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
        private readonly IDisponibilitaService _disponibilitaService;

        public UnitTest1()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), "directory", "Kalliope_CTI", "backend", "KalliopeCTITestProject"))
                .AddJsonFile("testconfig.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();



            services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, NullLoggerFactory>(); //< -- HERE TRY TO SET NullLoggerFactory


            var serviceProvider = services
                .AddOptions()
                .BuildServiceProvider();




        }


        //// your test methods
    }
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a shot in the dark, but you can try adding your `ILoggerProvider` to the `ILoggerFactory`:

```cs
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory();
var loggerProvider = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerProvider>();
loggerFactory.AddProvider(loggerProvider);
```

In case it was constructed sooner than you have registered your provider, it might not be aware of it's existance.

---

Alternatively, would it work, if you also tell it, how to resolve the `ILogger`?:

```cs
...
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyCustomProvider>(provider =>
{
    var myDependency = provider.GetService<IDependency>();
    return new MyCustomProvider(myDependency );
});
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), provider => 
{
    var loggerProvider = provider.GetService<ILoggerProvider>();
    return loggerProvider.CreateLogger("TestLogger");
});
...
```

---

Finally... is there a reason, why you can't just inject `ILoggerProvider` into your tests, and call `loggerProvider.CreateLogger(<test_class_name>)` to get the logger?