# ASP.NET Core logging to different database depending on User

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection, error-handling

I am trying to implement custom ILogger and ILoggerProvider classes. The goal is to use them within controllers to log eventually occuring Exceptions. So far so standard. Now comes the Problem: I want to log to different databases depending on the user (I get from HttpContext). How would that be possible?

I do not see how you can provide logger instances depending on user via DI to a controller. Nor do I see how I could give the logging Methods a (user)parameter.
I am somewhat new to asp.net core so maybe I am just to blind to see it. I would really appreciate some guidance

Comment: Do you have a fixed amount of databases or do you want a new database to be created for each new user?

Comment: There is a variable amount of project databases. Also there is one central database where the users and there reference to the project is stored. But the logging has to go into the project database of the user

Comment: This falls into the multi-tenant category where each tenant has its own DB. I suggest looking into ASP.NET Core multi-tenant implementations.

Comment: Maybe this can help : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991469/how-to-pass-dependencies-to-a-custom-net-core-iloggerprovider