# Blazor Server: ILogger to log to browser console

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using Blazor server, is it possible to define an implementation of ILogger that logs into the browser console?

To log to the browser, the logger needs access to IJSRuntime service. However:

- IJSRuntime is scoped
- There seems to be a circular dependency between IJSRuntime and ILoggerFactory

I've tried to setup the browser console logger provider this way but it creates an infinite recursive loop when calling "GetRequiredService":

```
public class BrowserLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
   public BrowserLoggerProvider(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      _services = services ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
   }

   public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
   {
      if (_browserLogger is not null)
      {
         return _browserLogger;
      }

      using ServiceProvider provider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
      IJSRuntime jsRuntime = provider.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
      _browserLogger = new BrowserLogger(jsRuntime);
      return _browserLogger;
   }
   
   public void Dispose()
   {
   }
   
   private BrowserLogger? _browserLogger;
   private readonly IServiceCollection _services;
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(options => options.AddProvider(new BrowserLoggerProvider(options.Services)));
```

Comment: `Blazor Server` means the code runs on the *server*, not the browser.  What you want essentially means sending log events to the browser and outputting them to the console. That's very expensive.

Comment: yes but this is just for development purposes

Comment: As for the error itself, it's caused because the code tries to create its own DI container on every call to `CreateLogger`. Your provider needs `IServiceProvider`, not `IServiceCollection`. `AddProvider` is essentially a call to `builder.Services.AddSingleton`. Check [How to pass dependencies to a custom .NET Core ILoggerProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991469/how-to-pass-dependencies-to-a-custom-net-core-iloggerprovider). Essentially, you treat your IJSRuntime dependency the same way as any other. The major issue is that the provider is Singleton but IJSRuntime is *scoped*

Comment: `just for development purposes` why not write to the *server* console or a proper log file then? What you want is very complicated. There will be more than one clients at a time so you need to know which messages to send to which console. That means you *can't* use `IServiceProvider`, you need access to the user's scope to get the correct IJSRuntime instance. Messages that aren't specific to a user will have to be sent to all of them. Things start getting very complicated, very quickly

Comment: You should probably check [.NET Aspire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/aspire-overview), mainly for its dashboard and the way it uses OpenTelemetry to send both traces and logs to a centralized location. The dashboard then displays both logs and traces in a developer-friendly way, similar and even better than a browser's Network and Console tabs.

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find resources for doing that. Thanks I'll take a look!

Comment: You an use an ObservalbeCollection and listen on the UI.